# How to prove the eigenvalues of $(A+B)^{-1}A$ are within $[0, 1)$, when $A$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

The eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $(A + B)^{-1}A$ is within $[0,1)$, where $A$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is positive definite. How to prove this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(A+B)^{-1}A x=\lambda x$ with $x \neq 0$. Then $Ax=\lambda (Ax+Bx)$ which gives $(1-\lambda) \langle Ax, x \rangle =\lambda \langle Bx, x \rangle$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you so much, and I just figured it out a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

$(A+B)^{-1}Ax = \lambda x$ and multiply $x^T(A+B)$ on the left to get:

$x^TAx = \lambda x^T(A + B)x$ and now it's easy to see the range of $\lambda$.